# Constrained combinations of balls in jars

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, balls-in-bins

Not sure how to solve the following problem. Imagine we have balls of $n$ different colors. There are $m$ balls of each color, so in total we have $nm$ number of balls.

The question is how many combinations are there to place these $nm$ marbles into $k$ jars keeping in mind that:

1. Each jar must have exactly $l$ balls ($l \leq n$ and $m < k$).
2. Each jar should not contain $2$ balls of the same color.

The second constraint makes the problem especially hard for me. I'm not sure where to start. If you could help me or point to the paper/article with similar problem, that would be great.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are the jars distinguishable? Eg. If we have 2 Red, 2 Blue, 2 Green balls and 3 jars, do you regard [RB|RG|BG] and [RB|BG|RG] (where jars 2 and 3 have swapped places) as different combinations or the same?

Comment: No, they are not. So these 2 cases are identical

Comment: Actually, I don't care. Either way is possible. In the end I need to calculate a probability of the above event to happen among all possible combinations of distributing $mn$ balls among k jars. So If I can get an equation for distinguishable or indistinguishable jars, that should work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding a closed form seems difficult. Here are some ideas.

Let us consider the case where the jars are numbered.

Consider a $n\times k$ matrix with every entry being either $0$ or $1$. If a ball of $i$ th type is present in $j$ th bin, then $(i,j)$ th entry of the matrix is $1$, else it is zero. Each column may be visualized as a 'bin'. We count the matrices such that

1. every column contains exactly $l$ ones.
2. every row contains at most $m$ ones.

Lets assume that $kl\le mn$ (else such matrices do not exist). The strategy is to count all the matrices with restriction (1) and then subtract the number of matrices that do not conform to restriction (2).

The number of matrices with the restriction (1) is ${\binom{n}{l}}^k$. Let $r_i$ be the row sum of the $1\le i\le n$ th row. We have the equation,
$$r_1+r_2+\dots +r_n=kl \quad \quad \quad \quad (A)$$

A solution of (A) where at least one $r_i$ exceeds $m$ (and $r_i\le k \quad \forall 1\le i\le n$) corresponds to some matrices that do not conform with (2). Number of such matrices is
$$\sum_{S}\binom{k}{r_1}\binom{k}{r_2}\cdots \binom{k}{r_n}$$ where $S=\{(r_1,r_2,\dots r_n), \sum r_i=kl \text{ AND at least one }r_i \text{ exceeds }m \}$

Hence the number of valid matrices is $${\binom{n}{l}}^k-\sum_{S}\binom{k}{r_1}\binom{k}{r_2}\cdots \binom{k}{r_n}$$
This is far from a closed form as we are iterating over a set of ordered tuples which are the solutions of (A)

---

**An upper bound**: We associate a solution of (A)  where at least one $r_i>m$ with a matrix where in every row, all the ones are stacked up to the left followed by $0$'s (if any). Each solution of (A)  where at least one $r_i>m$ corresponds to a unique matrix and vice versa.

Number of such solutions is (by inclusion-exclusion)
$$E:=\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor \frac{kl}{m+1}\rfloor}(-1)^{i+1}\binom{n}{i}\binom{kl-(m+1)i+n-1}{n-1}-\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor \frac{kl}{k+1}\rfloor}(-1)^{i+1}\binom{n}{i}\binom{kl-(k+1)i+n-1}{n-1}$$

Hence, the upper bound is ${\binom{n}{l}}^k-E$

The upper bound will be exact if $k=m+1$.

---

The case of identical bins seems still more harder.

Answer (score 0):

If you have $l$ balls in each jar, no colors repeated, that means each jar contains an $l$ subset of the colors, of which there are $\binom{n}{l}$. As there are enough marbles to do this all around (enough marbles of each color so you won't run out if you place one of each color in each jar), if you take the jars distinguishable (i.e., numbered for example), the number of ways of doing this is:
$$
\binom{n}{l}^k
$$

Comment: "if you take the jars distinguishable" ... and the balls non distinguishable

Comment: If I have n = 2, and k = 2 and l = 1 (and m = 1), that is, I  have n = 2 colors, 1 red, 1 blue ball and I want to put them into k = 2 jars with l = 1 ball in each jar then they can be R, B or B, R two ways. Does this formula work out?

Comment: This is the problem! Number of jars k is greater than number of each marble m. To be precise, m = k - 1, meaning that number of balls of each color is one less than number of jars. But this formula counts cases when we place marble of some color into k jars, while we have only k-1 marbles of this color.

Answer (score -1):

You need $l \times k=n \times m$, in which case we can be more specific and say $l<n$ and $m<k$, right?